# need to calculate screen height and bottom nav to get responsive margin but im not good at math

Tags: flutter, dart

i have `screen height 844` and bottom `kBottomNavigationBarHeight 87` and before bottomNav i have a button which i want to give a margin between the button and bottomNav to look like this

[image]

i want the margin to be responsive so in every device it will look like the image above, so i have a logic to get the margin height by calculating `screen height` and  `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` but i don't know how to calculate it or is there someway to achieve this better ?

what i've tried

```
 EdgeInsets.only(top: Get.height / kBottomNavigationBarHeight)
```

this is for full image of the screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen your full code but,

I assume you use Column to show all the widgets (since it overflows).
Maybe your code looks like this:

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        UpperPart(),
        MovieTitle(),
        MovieStats(),
        MovieDescription(),
        RatingButton(),
        BottomNav(),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to show the button over the bottom nav with the same height:

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        UpperPart(),
        MovieTitle(),
        MovieStats(),
        MovieDescription(),
        Spacer(), // fills the remaining space
        RatingButton(),
        SizedBox(height: 30), // Adjust this value to your specification. 
        BottomNav(),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

But this may not solve the overflow problem.
Maybe moving the Uppersection (UpperPart to MoviewDescription) to a scrollable widget may be the solution

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                UpperPart(),
                MovieTitle(),
                MovieStats(),
                MovieDescription(),
              ]
            )
          ),
        ),
        RatingButton(),
        SizedBox(height: 30), // Adjust this value to your specification. 
        BottomNav(),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

to correct dimension errors I usually use MediaQuery to measure the widgets that I will build by percentage

for example:

```
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .15, //  == 15% size screen
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5, //  == 50% size screen
// for margin I usually use symmetry
magin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5)

)
```